# Is there a way to fix this string output?

Tags: java, string, csv

I am reading data from a CSV file and putting the string into an array list called `album`. One of the string was: `The Beatles ("The White Album")` and the output when I print it using `System.out.print(album.get(index))` was:

```
"The Beatles (""The White Album"")"
```

Why are there extra quotation marks at the front and last and at between?

I tried replacing the quotation of the string with `\"` so that it takes quotation as a string too but the output was:

```
\"The Beatles (\\"The White Album\\")\
```

Code I tried:

```
System.out.print(album.get(index).replace('"','\\"');
```

Comment: csv file reader will probably quote `"` with `"` unless told to do something else.

Comment: How can I print the String from CSV as it is? Is it because of the quotation in the String from the CSV file?

Comment: Would be helpful if you provided a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

CSV separates values with commas:

```
value1,value2,value3
```

But what if the value itself contains a comma, like say `value,3`? No problem, says CSV, we'll put in in quotes:

```
value1,value2,"value,3"
```

So now the quotes are used to surround values with commas... what do we do if such a value itself contains a quote, like say, `value "3"`? No problem, says CSV, we'll replace the quote with a double quote:

```
value1,value2,"value ""3"""
```

---

In your case, what you probably want to do is this:

- If the string you read doesn't start with `"`, use it as is.
- If it does start with `"`:

  - substring it to cut the first and last characters - `str.substring(1, str.length() - 1)`
  - replace all occurrences of `""` with `"`